# What's the name of this pieces' design?

Tags: chess-set

Please can anyone help me to find the name of this chess pieces' design?

[image: Chess pieces]

Comment: That is a bog standard Staunton design that nowadays is almost universal.

Answer (score 4):

The shape of the pieces is a standard [Staunton chess set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staunton_chess_set). However, the marbled material makes it look rather unusual. I am not up on the rules about color use, but I have my doubts that it would be permitted in tournament use if one of the players objected.

Comment: "I have my doubts that it would be permitted in tournament use if one of the players objected" - I agree, because the colors are a bit odd to look at. Maybe even distracting!